# can't convert ArrayList<ModelClass> to JSONArray

Tags: arraylist, json, android-json

> here is my code

```
JSONObject jResult = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    for (int i=0; i < feedItemList.size(); i++) {
        JSONObject jGroup = new JSONObject();
        jGroup.put("contactId", feedItemList.get(i).getID());
        jGroup.put("contactName", feedItemList.get(i).getNAME());
        jGroup.put("contactNumber", feedItemList.get(i).getPHONE());

        JSONObject jOuter = new JSONObject();
        jsonArray.put(jOuter);
    }

    jResult.put("contact set",jsonArray);
    System.out.println("created json array"+jsonArray);
```

> my arraylist:-

```
List<CONTACT_MODEL> feedItemList = new ArrayList<CONTACT_MODEL>();
```

> i m getting result as below with no values:

["{}","{}","{}","{}","{}","{}","{}","{}","{}","{}","{}"]

> But I wanted to create an jsonarray like

```
[{"contactName":"Name 1","contactId":0,"contactNumber":"876654"},{"contactName":"Name 2","contactId":1,"contactNumber":"876677"},{"contactName":"Name 3","contactId":3,"contactNumber":"876678"}]
```

> can anyone tell me where i m doing wrong

Comment: hello is anyone there to help me out

Answer (score 0):

You are getting blank jsonArray because of this line:

```
jsonArray.put(jOuter);
```

You have created a jsonObject name jGroup but are putting jOuter in your array.
It should be:

```
jsonArray.put(jGroup );
```